# Managing Audio in A Native Android Application

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk

I am trying to write a native android application in which I want to play couple of audio streams. In order to have proper synchronization with other audio streams in rest of the android system, I need to manage playback of these streams properly. While programming in java, android framework provides APIs like 'AudioManager.requestAudioFocus', 'AudioManager.abandonAudioFocus' and also provides appropriate callbacks according to behavior of other audio streams. 
So, is there any possible way by means of which I can call these methods from a native code ? 
It seems there is one more way of using OpenSL APIs. Does OpenSl provides methods similar to requestAudioFocus / abandonAudioFocus ?

Thanks in advance